# How do we chain multiple promises that should happen one by one using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

Is the following how we chain multiple promises in jQuery (1.8 and later)?

```
foo()
  .then(function() { return bar(); })
  .then(function() { return wah(); })   
  .then(function() { return lah(); })
  .then(function() { return haha(); });
```

where all `foo()`, `bar()`, `wah()`, `lah()`, `haha()` have to return a promise.

I think one note is that we have to use `then()` instead of `done()`, because if we use `done()`, then the second action to the last action will all be started after action 1 is done, instead of one by one.

---

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/jq9d3tw1/

```
changeStyle($("#message1"), { fontSize: "3em" }, 3000)
  .then(function() { return changeStyle($("#message2"), { marginLeft: "100px" }, 2000) })
  .then(function() { return changeStyle($("#message3"), { opacity: 0 }, 1000) });
```

where `changeStyle()` creates a deferred, gets the promise, performs some action and resolves the promise when done, and returns that promise:

```
function changeStyle(element, style, duration) {

  var d = new $.Deferred(),
      p = d.promise();

  element.animate(style, duration, function() {
    d.resolve();
  });

  return p;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this article, it explains chaining multiple promises reall well: https://medium.com/coding-design/writing-better-ajax-8ee4a7fb95f#.69uyza4nj

Comment: `where all foo(), bar(), wah(), lah(), haha() have to return a promise` - in the code snippet you posted, only foo **has to** return a promise, the others *can* but it's not *required* for proper Promise/A+ functionality - of course, some early jQuery implementations of "promises" (or more correctly for jQuery, Deferred's) were not exactly Promise/A (let alone Promise/A+) compliant, so, perhaps you are right that those function **have to** return a Promise

Comment: @JaromandaX if the second and later ones *do not* return a promise, as in https://jsfiddle.net/jq9d3tw1/3/ using `changeStyle2`, then animation 2 and 3 happen at the same time, not one by one

Comment: You misunderstand. I merely corrected an incorrect general statement.

Comment: so are you saying in order to do it one by one, the 2nd to last function do not have to return a promise? do you have an example of that working? because https://jsfiddle.net/jq9d3tw1/3/ doesn't

Answer (score 2):

You can make the code a bit more concise by using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for the `then` callback, and the [`.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) method on the animated element:

```js
changeStyle($("#message1"), { fontSize: "3em" }, 3000)
  .then(changeStyle.bind($, $("#message2"), { marginLeft: "100px" }, 2000))
  .then(changeStyle.bind($, $("#message3"), { opacity: 0 }, 1000));

function changeStyle(element, style, duration) {
  return element.animate(style, duration).promise();
}
```

```css
body { font: 24px Arial, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message1">hello</div>
<div id="message2">hi</div>
<div id="message3">ha</div>
```

Comment: I'd rather bind to `null` though when it is not necessary, instead of `$`.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular use case, jQuery gives you functionality to do this type of thing out of the box using a [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/). By default, the `fx` queue applies to animations, including built-in ones like `fadeIn()`, `slideUp()`, etc.

In this case, the `done` function triggers the effect on the next element once the current element's animation is complete.

```
var $message1 = $('#message1');
var $message2 = $('#message2');
var $message3 = $('#message3');
$message1.queue(function() {
    $(this).animate(
      { fontSize: "3em" }, 
      {
        duration: 3000, 
        done : function() { $message2.dequeue(); }
      }
    );
});
$message2.queue(function() {
    $(this).animate(
      { marginLeft: "100px" },
      {
        duration: 2000, 
        done : function() { $message3.dequeue(); }
      }
    );
});
$message3.queue(function() {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
});
$message1.dequeue(); // initiate the first effect
```

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzy_og_kush/3mnay5fk/) for an example

Answer (score -2):

This code can be even simpler if you are returning promise - you do not need to create anonimous function inside

```
changeStyle($("#message1"), { fontSize: "3em" }, 3000)
  .then(changeStyle($("#message2"), { marginLeft: "100px" }, 2000))
  .then(changeStyle($("#message3"), { opacity: 0 }, 1000));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/jq9d3tw1/1/

Comment: are you sure... I see all animations happening all at once, instead of one by one

Comment: no no no no - any argument(s) to `.then` that are not functions are effectively ignored - this is not chaining anything

Comment: but will be evaluated so it can take action if it is a function (function invoked)

Comment: indeed, functions will be invoked immediately, so the code above is like calling each changeStyle just like the first with no `.then( ... )`